# Error while using create react app command

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Even though everything used to work couple of weeks ago, now I can not successfully create new react app with its templates.

When I try to run npx create-react-app my-app command, it only creates the folder with package.json, pckage-lock.json and node_modules. The public folder is missing and also, when I try to run npm start, it gives me an error saying:

```
npm ERR! missing script: start
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

before it used to say happy hacking and the template page with react logo was displayed.

I tried to uninstall and install node again, clear cache but nothing helped. Any advice? Thank you so much!

My npm -v is 6.13.4 and node -v is v12.14.0

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8088

Comment: did you installed create react app globally ?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS yes I did!

Comment: which system are you using ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing Script when I run npm start to create React app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56148511/missing-script-when-i-run-npm-start-to-create-react-app)

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS is there any way of uninstalling node and installing it again from scratch. I tried everything but I keep getting error: 

A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.

Comment: @n0noob thank you.  I followed it but when I run the create-react-app command it gives me the same error. A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.

Comment: @PetraJakubcova which system are you using windows, ubuntu or mac ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed `create-react-app` globally. remove that globally from you system

Try these steps

1. `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
2. `npx create-react-app app_name
   cd app_name
   npm start`

> Note- npx comes with npm 5.2+ and higher, see instructions for older
>   npm versions

Check this [reactjs documentation.](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/)

Comment: Thank you. I uninstalled it and ran npx create-react-app but it gave me this error:

+ react-dom@16.12.0
+ react-scripts@3.3.0
+ react@16.12.0
added 1674 packages from 765 contributors and audited 906205 packages in 93.644s

32 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities


A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

First, update the `npm` and `node` using following commands:

```
npm install -g npm
npm cache clean -f
npm install -g n
n stable
```

Remove globally installed `create-react-app` using:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

Use npx for using `create-react-app` directly:

```
npx create-react-app <project-name>
```

Comment: BTW you should not install `create-react-app` globally. [This](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#quick-overview) page says that they recommend uninstalling to ensure `npx` is always using the latest version

Comment: Updated my answer. The main point that I want to emphasize here is that ```node``` and ```npm``` should updated.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue and fixed it by following the below steps:

1. Try to uninstall all existing global installation of `create-react-app` and check that they are removed properly by using the two commands below:

   - command for uninstalling: `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`
   - command for checking: `which create-react-app`
   - command for manual delete: `rm -rf <path where create react app is located>`
2. Once all the versions are removed, use: `npx create-react-app <name_of_the_app>`

For more details refer [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8097)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, and saw a lot of the same answers saying to uninstall `create-react-app` globally and reinstall using `npx create-react-app my-app`.

[Downgrading my version of Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47008159/how-to-downgrade-node-version) to 8.11.1 is what fixed it.

```
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 8.11.1
node -v
> v8.11.1
```

After that I ran `npx create-react-app my-app` and it worked as expected.