# REACT npm start command

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I just created a react app by using the create-react-app command and I gave the app the name `react-app`. I followed these steps

- `cd` into that directory using `cd react-app/`
- running the `npm start` command

I ran into an error that says;

> ```
> npm ERR! Missing scripts: start
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> C:\Users\user\Appdata\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-09T07_00_18_996z-debug.log
> ```

---

**Edit:** Here is the content of my *package.json*:

```json
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0"
  }
}
```

---

Adding those scripts to my package.js worked but initiated another issue. Here is the snippet. Thanks folks [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKOkC.png)

Comment: npm i react-scripts

Comment: maybe this link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976722/start-script-missing-error-when-running-npm-start#:~:text=If%20there%20is%20a%20server,js.&text=This%20error%20also%20happens%20if,script%22%20key%20in%20the%20package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing Script when I run npm start to create React app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56148511/missing-script-when-i-run-npm-start-to-create-react-app)

Comment: Thanks @Ntshembo Hlongwane. The link was pretty helpful.  I appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have these scripts at your package.json.

**My package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```